# UIWebView not calling shouldStartLoadWithRequest on Button with dynamic link

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm currently accessing webpage which another team has built to cover some functionality in an app (therefore I can't change the webpage) and I've hit something of a small problem. One of the buttons, which is only activated (via `Javascript`) once certain requisites are fulfilled, refuses to be noticed by the `UIWebView` when it has been activated and click. That means `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` doesn't get called and I need it to, to perform some functionality. I was looking at the source and the button doesn't have an `HREF` initially, which I think may be confusing the UIWebView. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can make the `UIWebView` notice this button?

Thanks,
Mike

**HTML of Button:**

If there isn't a URL: `<a class="ts_btn book_btn" href="">Book</a>` 
If there is a URL: `<a class="ts_btn book_btn" href="/bookings/new?date=2013-10-10&amp;bus_id=2&amp;slot_number=9">Book </a>`

Comment: Is it possible to post the code involving this button? Also what do you mean by 'initially', is the `href` added dynamically to the element after activation? Can you describe this procedure?

Comment: @Alladinian Hi, I can get the html css of the button if you want. Well initially when the web page is loaded the HREF is set to nothing. However, when the user fills in the required forms, the HREF is updated using a javascript, which links the user to the correct page. It is all done dynamically

Comment: Is the button href pointing to the correct web page?

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to modify the href in the webview, using the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString call

```
NSString *js = @"document.getElementById('mybuttonid').setAttribute('href','http://www.dummylink.com/')";

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js];
```

Then you can use the

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType
```

To actually ignore the link and perform the functionality that you require.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Nick. The issue is, I have no idea how to generate the link. That is done on the server and was created by someone else, not me. +1 though, as it's getting closer.

Comment: Yea sure, check the update to the original question for the HTML. I've actually come up with a nasty work around to the situation by checking the URL using javasript every 0.5s, but it really isn't nice to use.

Answer (score 1):

if i am not wrong you want to open link in iPhone Browser from UIWebView. Means When user click on button it will redirect in iPhone Browser. If i am right than please try use the below steps otherwise please comment on below that i am wrong. i will don't mind:

1. Add UIWebViewDelegate in to your header Class (.h File)
2. Add Below Method in Your Method Class (.m File)

   ```
   #pragma mark - Webview Delegate Methods
   -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType 
   {
         if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) 
         {
              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
              return NO;
         }
       return YES;
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Perhaps I didn't explain my self correctly. The button in the UIWebView takes the user to another page on the website, however, `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is not called when this happens.

Comment: i think there is something problem. please add the URL in UIWebView and click on the URL. I am sure the above method called. if you have a CSS file than try to add below code in one of webview delegate methods:

Comment: - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *cssPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"style.css"];
    
    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var cssChild = document.createElement('link');"
                    "cssChild = 'text/css';"
                    "cssChild = 'stylesheet';"
                    "cssChild = '%@';", cssPath];
    js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssChild);", js];
    [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}